# Best Implementation of: Airport/Train Station departure board (html/css/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can any please point me to an implementation of a Train Station Departure board that uses HTML/CSS/jQuery?

Comment: How do you mean? Explain your question more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does this suit your needs? (not mine, but nice execution).

http://jsfiddle.net/aino/9yyVd/

Comment: nice. i wonder who did it!

Comment: If I recall correctly it was done by David Hellsing of galleria.js fame http://galleria.io/

Comment: Excellent! One note: in line 9 of the JS, the alphabet is missing the "W". So if there's a "W" in your list it will cycle forever.