# Flight board effect using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a flight board effect using jquery.

So far i have been able to create an effect that rotates characters. Here's what I have achieved so far: http://www.jaspreetkaur.com/chatter/

See the text "get to the chatter that matters"

However O do not feel this effect is realistic. I want the text flip to be like http://nolanow.cacno.org/ (see the word NOW in logo) This effect is created with help of images.

I do not want to use images to keep the effect reusable, so how can i create the effect without use of images?

Comment: You might find this post useful; [Best Implementation of: Airport/Train Station departure board (html/css/jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869405/best-implementation-of-airport-train-station-departure-board-html-css-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Matt, i have already created that effect, what i want to add is flip effect as shown here http://nolanow.cacno.org/

Comment: I have used Flash to create this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the effect upto some extent, here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/QZuku/

I am still trying to improve the code however to make it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

try using a font like [YonderRecoil](http://www.1001fonts.com/font_details.html?font_id=3096) - just an example, there are bound to be better fonts than this one out there

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same effect and couldn't really find a library that did it the way I wanted, so I created a jsFiddle with the effect as well in case anyone is still interested in this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jacoswarts/neUtP/

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="front open">5</div>
  <div class="back close">4</div>
  <div class="flap top"></div>
  <div class="axis"></div>
</div>
```

The HTML is a bit bulky, so converting it into a jquery plugin that injects the boards would be nice.