# Trying to refactor this Javascript and coming unstuck

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a website, and part of the content will be a live 'departures board' ticker, as such:

[image: departures board]

I'm very experienced at C#, but have absolutely no experience with Javascript.

I've found the following Javascript [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869405/best-implementation-of-airport-train-station-departure-board-html-css-jquery) which almost does what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.fn.ticker = function (options) {

        options = $.extend({
            speed: 30
        }, options);

        var alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ01234567890,.:+=/();!- ';

        return this.each(function () {
            var k = 1,
            elems = $(this).children(),
            arr = alph.split(''),
            len = 0,
            fill = function (a) {
                while (a.length < len) {
                    a.push(' ');
                }
                return a;
            },
            texts = $.map(elems, function (elem) {
                var text = $(elem).text();
                len = Math.max(len, text.length);
                return text.toUpperCase();
            }),
            target = $('<div>'),
            render = function (print) {
                target.data('prev', print.join(''));
                fill(print);
                print = $.map(print, function (p) {
                    return p == ' ' ? '&#160;' : p;
                });
                return target.html('<span>' + print.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
            },
            attr = {}

            $.each(this.attributes, function (i, item) {
                target.attr(item.name, item.value);
            });

            $(this).replaceWith(render(texts[0].split('')));

            target.click(function (e) {

                var next = fill(texts[k].split('')),
                prev = fill(target.data('prev').split('')),
                print = prev;

                $.each(next, function (i) {
                    if (next[i] == prev[i]) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var index = alph.indexOf(prev[i]),
                    j = 0,
                    tid = window.setInterval(function () {
                        if (next[i] != arr[index]) {
                            index = index == alph.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
                        } else {
                            window.clearInterval(tid);
                        }
                        print[i] = alph[index];
                        render(print);
                    }, options.speed)
                });
                k = k == texts.length - 1 ? 0 : k + 1;
            });
        });
    };


    // Assign functions
    $('#mainfeatureslist').ticker();

    // Click it now
    $('#mainfeatureslist').click();


</script>
```

...combined with the necessary include of JQuery and the appropriate HTML:

```
<div id="mainfeatureslistcontainer">
<ul id="mainfeatureslist">
<li>Live bus arrivals</li>
<li>Another feature here</li>
<li>Name of third feature</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This code generates a list which, when clicked, transitions to the next list item.

However, I want the list to automatically transition at a set interval, with no clicks required.

I've tried a simple fudge, i.e.

```
setInterval($('#mainfeatureslist').click(), 6000);
```

...but this seems to confuse it for some reason; it interrupts the process and 'jumps' to an item, then nothing further happens.

Despite having a reasonable idea of what the code does, I've absolutely no idea how to re-factor it to do what I want!  It seems hard-wired to generate its own .click methods - in fact, it is a very brilliant and compact piece of code.

How do I refactor this to 'flip' the list every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setInterval` expects a *function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) - right now you are passing in the return value of some function call (in this case a jQuery object). Use an anonymous function containing the code you want to execute instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#mainfeatureslist').click();
}, 6000);
```

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you.  I'm not really sure what to do, as you've solved my problem, but haven't answered the question.  I think I'll wait and see if anyone is able to re-factor the code and, if nobody does, will accept this answer.  Shout if that seems unfair.

Comment: Depending on whether you need the event object generated by the click event you might also be able to just use the jQuery object's click method itself: setInterval($('#mainfeatureslist').click, 6000)

Comment: @natlee75: That cannot work. The method will have `this === window` instead of the correct element. Besides that the method will be called with an argument (the event object) which might also cause problems.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I know. I didn't see that `this` came into play in the code, but I also didn't inspect the code THAT closely. :-)

Comment: @CarlosP: Are you seriously asking someone here to completely refactor that entire piece of code for you? I'm pretty sure that's not what Stack Overflow is really for...

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm just looking for some pointers as to where to start; I find all the inline functions rather overwhelming. I was hoping that somebody might outline the bare essentials of what I need to do, ideally with some skeleton code.  I don't expect the whole thing to be re-written, but I know this is a place where people help each other out.  See my other answers for proof I'm not just a leech; I've posted code samples before.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is be a better place for this. Anonymous/inline functions are pretty common in modern JavaScript code by the way and trying to get rid of them easily results in less readable code.

Comment: @CarlosP: Understood. I think it was just the wording of the request that seemed a bit off. The first thing I'd look at is the code block that starts with `target.click`. Maybe try taking that entire anonymous function that's passed in there as an argument and use that as the function argument for a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` call. Do this within the context of the `ticker` jQuery plugin and not outside in the surrounding context.

Comment: @CarlosP: If you're still stuck just go with ThiefMaster's suggestion of hitting up codereview.stackexchange.com. And accept ThiefMaster's answer! :-)